# unable to overwrite the existing bar amchart with a new amchart based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I am populating amcharts on a button click based on the current financial year ie 2018-2019.
The code is as follows:

```
function populateChartsBarFY(requestUriFY) {
var chartDataResults2 = [];
var AmountCollectedFYBar = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: requestUriFY,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var dataResults = data.d.results;
        var clr;
        for (i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
            var chartItems = dataResults[i];         
            var dist = chartItems.District;
            var MineralCategory = chartItems.MineralCategory;
            AmountCollectedFYBar = parseFloat(chartItems.LastMonthCollection);
            if (MineralCategory == "Major" ) {
                clr = "#67B7DC";                
            }
            else if (MineralCategory == "Minor" ) {
                clr = "#FDD302";        
            }
            else if (MineralCategory == "Others" ) {           
                clr = "#83B762";            
            }
            var flag = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < chartDataResults2.length; j++) {
                if (chartDataResults2[j].MineralCategory == MineralCategory) {
                    chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected = (chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected + AmountCollectedFYBar);
                    chartDataResults2[j].balloonTextField=( dist + "," + MineralCategory + "," + (chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected));
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag == false) {
                chartDataResults2.push({
                    States: dist,
                    MineralCategory : MineralCategory,
                    AmountCollected: AmountCollectedFYBar,
                    "color": clr,
                    balloonTextField: dist + "," + MineralCategory + "," + AmountCollectedFYBar,
                });
            }

            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivdistFY", {
               type: "serial",               
              dataProvider: chartDataResults2,
              categoryField: "MineralCategory",
              categoryAxis: {
              labelRotation: 90,
              gridPosition: "start",
             gridThickness: 0,
             },              
              graphs: [ {
            valueField: "AmountCollected",
             type: "column",
              fillAlphas: 0.8,                
                colorField: "color",
                balloonText :"[[balloonTextField]]",
               labelText : "[[value]]",          
                type : "column",
                lineAlpha :0,               
                fixedColumnWidth :25
           } ],
         chartCursor: {
         cursorPosition: "mouse"
         },
         valueAxis:
         {
             dashLength:5,
             title:"Collected Amount",
            gridThickness:0,
             axisAlpha:0,
         },
         }); 

            });// JavaScript source code
        } // for
    }, //success
}); //ajax  
AmountCollectedFYBar = 0;
} //populate charts
```

If I change the current year selection value fro '2018-2019' to '2015-2016' from dropdown and pass it to requestUriFY my new chart is not getting overwritten.

Anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code:

1) `AmCharts.ready` is simply a `window.onload`/`$(document).ready` assignment. It only runs the code inside `AmCharts.ready` on page load so calling it again will do nothing. Moving the `AmCharts.makeChart` call outside of `AmCharts.ready` will fix part of your problem.

2) You're creating the same chart in the for loop as you're constructing your data, which doesn't make sense at all. Move the `AmCharts.makeChart` call outside of the loop so that it only gets called once after your data is fully assigned to your `chartDataResults2` array.

3) You're re-creating the chart at the same div without clearing the previous instance, which will consume more resources and will cause visual artifacts due to the previous chart instance trying to redraw itself. I recommend storing the chart reference in a global and storing the chart object returned from `AmCharts.makeChart` on first load, then updating the dataProvider directly and calling [`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) to redraw the chart with your new data when the function is called again from your dropdown.

Full fix below:

```
var chart; //store the chart in a global that your populate function can refer to

function populateChartsBarFY(requestUriFY) {
  var chartDataResults2 = [];
  var AmountCollectedFYBar = 0;
  $.ajax({
    url: requestUriFY,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {
      "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var dataResults = data.d.results;
      var clr;
      for (i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
        var chartItems = dataResults[i];
        var dist = chartItems.District;
        var MineralCategory = chartItems.MineralCategory;
        AmountCollectedFYBar = parseFloat(chartItems.LastMonthCollection);
        if (MineralCategory == "Major") {
          clr = "#67B7DC";
        } else if (MineralCategory == "Minor") {
          clr = "#FDD302";
        } else if (MineralCategory == "Others") {
          clr = "#83B762";
        }
        var flag = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < chartDataResults2.length; j++) {
          if (chartDataResults2[j].MineralCategory == MineralCategory) {
            chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected = (chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected + AmountCollectedFYBar);
            chartDataResults2[j].balloonTextField = (dist + "," + MineralCategory + "," + (chartDataResults2[j].AmountCollected));
            flag = true;
          }
        }
        if (flag == false) {
          chartDataResults2.push({
            States: dist,
            MineralCategory: MineralCategory,
            AmountCollected: AmountCollectedFYBar,
            "color": clr,
            balloonTextField: dist + "," + MineralCategory + "," + AmountCollectedFYBar,
          });
        } 

      } // for

      if (!chart) { //if the chart variable isn't defined, do the first makeChart call and store the reference
        // SERIAL CHART
        chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivdistFY", {
          type: "serial",
          dataProvider: chartDataResults2,
          categoryField: "MineralCategory",
          categoryAxis: {
            labelRotation: 90,
            gridPosition: "start",
            gridThickness: 0,
          },
          graphs: [{
            valueField: "AmountCollected",
            type: "column",
            fillAlphas: 0.8,
            colorField: "color",
            balloonText: "[[balloonTextField]]",
            labelText: "[[value]]",
            type: "column",
            lineAlpha: 0,
            fixedColumnWidth: 25
          }],
          chartCursor: {
            cursorPosition: "mouse"
          },
          valueAxis: {
            dashLength: 5,
            title: "Collected Amount",
            gridThickness: 0,
            axisAlpha: 0,
          },
        });
      }
      else {
        //if the chart is defined, update the dataProvider with your new array and redraw with validateData:
        chart.dataProvider = chartDataResults2;
        chart.validateData()
      }

    }, //success
  }); //ajax  
  AmountCollectedFYBar = 0;
} //populate charts
```